# Why does Material 3 contains no color for success, while there is one for error?

Tags: design-patterns, material-design

Why does Material 3 contains no color for **success**, while there is one for **error**? Seems a bit asymmetric?

Wonder if this is intentional, as in: "success is a normal flow, no further color semantics are expected, they are distracting"

Or is there some other thinking?

Comment: the "why" typically is impossible to answer unless the original author chimes in. Your theory is probably a good one, but then, I found the M3 specs a lot less complete than M2 specs in general.

Comment: When a button is clicked for Success, what do you expect to happen? For example, a Submit button, when successful, shows a page saying what happened.

Comment: @Steve yes, page is shown and that resulting page will often have some success or error visual semantics, depending on app state. error visuals readily have color tokens available in M3, but how about tokens for success visuals?